# Flutter: Is there a way to build a complex widget asynchronously without blocking main isolate?

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I want to display a DataTable where the data input varies based on the user's input (the user can pick a csv file and its content will then be displayed in the DataTable widget).

My problem is that the DataTable creation can take a few seconds depending on the number of rows and columns in the user's csv file and the screen freezes in the meantime, which is obviously a bad user experience. Therefore, my idea was to create the DataTable in a separate isolate, await the result (see code below) and show a CircularProgressIndicator while waiting for the result.

Unfortunately, this approach is not working (I assume because CustomDataTable is not a valid [message type](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/SendPort/send.html)).

My approach using isolates here might be wrong (I am fairly new to flutter) and I am happy to switch to a different strategy if one can guide me in the right direction.

```
// In the class of my Stateful Widget that will display the CustomDataTable I have this function spawning the isolate and awaiting the CustomDataTable
Future<CustomDataTable> createCustomTableInIsolate(List<Map<String, String>> data, List<Map<String, String>> selectedRows, List<String> columnNames, Function onSelectedRow) async {
  var map = {
    'data': data,
    'selectedRows': selectedRows,
    'columnNames': columnNames,
    'onSelectedRow': onSelectedRow,
  };

  CustomDataTable dataTable = await compute(createCustomTable, map);
  return dataTable;
}

//... somewhere in my widget tree
FutureBuilder<CustomDataTable>(
    future: createCustomTableInIsolate(),
    builder: (BuildContext ctx,
        AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState ==
          ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
      } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Center(
              child: Text('Please check your input data...'),
            );
      } else {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minWidth: constraints.minWidth,
              ),
              child: snapshot.data),
        );
      }
    },
  ),
// ... 

// Function creating the CustomDataTable in different isolate (outside of stateful widget class)
CustomDataTable createCustomTable(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
  return CustomDataTable(
    data: map['data'],
    selectedRows: map['selectedRows'],
    columnNames: map['columnNames'],
    onSelectedRow: map['onSelectedRow'],
  );
}

// Separate class to create the DataTable widget
class CustomDataTable extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, String>> data;
  final List<Map<String, String>> selectedRows;
  final List<String> columnNames;
  final Function onSelectedRow;

  CustomDataTable({
    @required this.data,
    @required this.selectedRows,
    @required this.columnNames,
    @required this.onSelectedRow,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DataTable(
      columns: columnNames.map((columnName) {
        return DataColumn(
          label: Text(
            columnName,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
      rows: data.map((column) {
        var columnValues = column.values;
        return DataRow(
            selected: selectedRows.contains(column),
            onSelectChanged: (selected) {
              onSelectedRow(selected, column);
            },
            cells: columnValues.map((cellValue) {
              return DataCell(
                Text(
                  cellValue,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }).toList());
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how big is your input file? how do you read its content?

Comment: @pskink The file size can vary but I already notice lags with for example 50 rows and 5 columns (file size: 8KB). I use the [csv package](https://pub.dev/packages/csv) to read the content.

Comment: few seconds for 8KB file? then the package you are using is most likely broken (i though we are talking about couple of MB...)

Comment: The problem is not reading the file content (this is lightning fast), but displaying the data in the DataTable widget. Building the DataTable widgets takes some seconds for the above scenario.

Comment: `DataTable` docs say: *"Displaying data in a table is expensive, because to lay out the table all the data must be measured twice, once to negotiate the dimensions to use for each column, and once to actually lay out the table given the results of the negotiation.

For this reason, if you have a lot of data (say, more than a dozen rows with a dozen columns, though the precise limits depend on the target device), it is suggested that you use a PaginatedDataTable which automatically splits the data into multiple pages."*

Comment: Yes, I have read this and I might give the PaginatedDataTable a try. Thanks! I was wondering, however, if there is in general a possibility to build widgets asynchronously using isolates (or using some other approach)?

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem. I've created a feature request for this on the flutter github repository: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/84180

Answer (score 0):

Call individually
otherwise use an unique id in the row that already existed in the table row
that makes the data show with out any error